# Too Many Connection Error in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

i Have one C# desktop application  that connects mysql database sever.
The applicaiton runs well but after some time or some days it gives an exception like:

```
9/16/2013 12:56:55 PM: 9/16/2013 12:56:55 PM: Exception Occurred. Too many    
connections.StackTrace:    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.OpenPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate411()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
at ReckonHelper.MySqlDatabaseConnection.ConnectDB().
```

I don't know why it is being happen??

Any Solution For this?

Comment: Do you close/dispose the connections anywhere?

Comment: This happens very often in MySql if you forget to close AND DISPOSE the connections opened. Remember, an exception could leave behind an open connection if not propertly handled. ([Hint Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx))

Comment: I have used close command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Close the connection once you have complated the execution of SQL statements.
2. Use try..catch..finally

   ```
    try
    {
      ....... 
      con.Open();
      //execute sql statement

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
           throw ex;
           //throw or dispaly your exception
     }
    finally
    {
      con.close;
     }
   ```
3. Add the pooling attributes in your connection string 
           "Server=servername;Port=3306;Database=dbname; Uid=username;Pwd=password;pooling=true;Allow Zero Datetime=True;Min Pool Size=5; Max Pool Size=100;"

Comment: Or better `using(..){...}`

Comment: well ,i have used try..catch..Finally. second option :setting pooling attributes should work .

Comment: Run the command SHOW PROCESSLIST; on your MySQl GUI. It will show the current process list which is connecting your database. If you are seeing more process list just kill all the unwanted process (Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html)